# 2nd request to getServerSideProps fails to update/hydrate in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, hydration, getserversideprops

I am using a component to render a page, and I am using dynamic routes. I am pre-rendering using `getServerSideProps`, and now data of the page can change based on the route.

When the page is first loaded, the SSR returns HTML and the data and correctly renders the page.

When I click on the link present on the page in Link tag of next js, `getServerSideProps` returns a `json` object, but not the HTML so the data changes, but the component fails to re-render/ or the data on the page is still old one.

If I use anchor `<a>` tag in place of link tag then the page refreshes and it is working but it do not give a single page application feeling.

I tried `router.replace(router.asPath)` in the component, but that do not work. only changing link tag with a tag works but that refreshes the full page and the experience is not good.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.